# Need help with computational and numerical methods for solve equations

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

This is my first question on this community. I am a applied scientist, not a mathematician.

I have the following simplified problem:

Let $u: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ a real valued function and $k\in \mathbb{R}$.
The function $u(\cdot)$ is decreasing and may be continuous or not.
Let $x^*(k)$ the value that satisfies $$ u\left(x^*(k)\right) = k. $$

I need to get the numerical value $x^*(k)$ for any arbitrary $u(\cdot)$, using a computational `Rscript`.

Intuitively, I have decided to follow this procedure: 
I define a deviation $e(x) = k - u(x)$. Valued at $x^*(k)$, $e\left(x^*(k)\right) = 0$. Then, $x^*(k)$ minimizes the squared deviation or the absolute value deviation.
$$ x^*(k) = \arg \min_{x\in [0,1]} e(x)^2. $$

The code is not the problem. I wrote a script that return the graph of function $x^*(k)$ using any decreasing function $u$, i.e. $u=ae^{-bx}$, $u=a - bx^2$, ..., or other more complicated examples.

Now, I want to known:

1. What is the mathematical/theoretical name of this procedure?
2. In which bibliography can I learn about that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to approach this but generally-speaking your problem is not one that can be solved algorithmically.  Provided your function $u$ isn't too unreasonable, you have a lot of methods at your disposal.  Using a mid-point method on the intervals where $u$ is continuous would be one.   How is your function $u$ defined?

Comment: I edited my question with more details about $u$ definition.

Comment: Thanks! I will change to regula falsi methods. Now I known its names!!.

Comment: Start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm, or (even better) from any undergraduate numerical analysis book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squaring a function to find its zeroes is generally no good idea; first you can't exploit sign changes of the function values to conclude that a certain intervall must contain a zero (or discontinuity with sign change for left and right limit); another problem is that numeric precision gets worse because the slopes vanish at the zeros of the squared function.

Worst case scenario is that a sign transition may not result in a zero of the squared function, e.g.
$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{-(x-0.5)},  & x < 0.5 \\
+\sqrt{+(x-0.5)}+2k, & x \ge 0.5
\end{cases}
 $$
squaring yields
$$
(f(x)-k)^2=abs(x-0.5)+k
$$

the original transition from $0$ to $2k$ doesn't generate a zero and applying a derivative-based method like Newton-Raphson produces a ping pong between $0.5-k$ and $0.5+k$.

The Numerical Recipes book is probably the best resource to recommend to you.